# Conditional Counting in Mathematica

Tags: count, wolfram-mathematica, conditional-statements

Considering the following list :

```
dalist = {{1, a, 1}, {2, s, 0}, {1, d, 0}, {2, f, 0}, {1, g, 1}}
```

[image]

I would like to count the number of times a certain value in the first column takes a certain value in column 3.

So in this example my desired output would be:

{{1,1,2},
{1,0,1},
{2,1,0},
{2,0,2}}

or :

[image]

Where the latest sublist {2,0,2} being read as: When the value is 2 in the first column, a corresponding value (same row in matrices world) in column 3 of 0 is present twice.

I hope this is not to confusing. I added the second Column to convey the fact that the columns are distant to each other.

If possible, no reordering should happen.

EDIT :

{1,2,3,4,5}

{1,0}

are the exact values taken by the columns I am actually dealing with in my data.

I know I am missing the correct description. Please edit if you can and know it. Thank you

Comment: Your specs are currently not complete. For instance, you included {2,1,0} in the results, but why? Shouldn't you then also include {10,10,0} and {3.1415,2.718,0} and an infinite number of others? I assume the value ranges contained in each column should be restricted to certain values,  but then those should be specified.

Comment: @Sjoerd, thank you the comment and edit. Is the above Edit clear ?

Comment: No, if you don't restrict the allowed numerical values to a given, finite set then the number of {col1, col3} pairs that has a _count of zero_ is infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to come up with something brand new using Sasha's assumptions about the required output, but it got more similar to his code than I thought it would be. Still the differences are interesting enough to post.

```
   {#1, #2, Count[dalist[[All, {1, 3}]], {##}]} & @@@ 
    Tuples[
       {DeleteDuplicates@dalist[[All, 1]], 
        DeleteDuplicates@dalist[[All, 3]]}
    ]
```

**Edit**
With your clarification about the input the code can be simplified and actually improved to:

```
   {#1, #2, Count[dalist[[All, {1, 3}]], {##}]}& @@@Tuples[{Range[5],{0,1}}]
```

The first version is correct only if at least one example of each possible outcome is actually present in each column.

Comment: +1. But note that the `Count` - based approach will be a performance disaster for large lists. Within this formulation, I'd do something like `With[{data = dalist[[All, {1, 3}]]}, Flatten /@ Transpose[{#, # /. 
 Dispatch[Append[Rule @@@ Tally[data], {_, _} -> 0]]}] &[Tuples[DeleteDuplicates /@ Transpose@data]]]`. You can try on test data like `testData = RandomInteger[200, {400, 3}]` to see the difference.

Answer (score 4):

From what I understood, this should do it:

```
In[11]:= dalist = {{1, a, 1}, {2, s, 0}, {1, d, 0}, {2, f, 0}, {1, g, 1}}

Out[11]= {{1, a, 1}, {2, s, 0}, {1, d, 0}, {2, f, 0}, {1, g, 1}}

In[12]:= Map[Flatten, Tally[dalist[[All, {1, 3}]]]]

Out[12]= {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 1}}
```

In your sample, you don't actually have the combination {2,1}, but you have the combination {2,0} twice, not once - thus the output is different from what you anticipated. That is, if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: I did exactly the same, but was trying to resolve the output issue with @500 first

Comment: @Sjoerd I think, @500 just made a mistake in his typing as well as counting. He probably meant `{2,1,1},{2,0,1}`, which would also not correspond to his set of data. I can easily delete this post so that you can post your solution instead.

Comment: No, please don't. It's all in the game.

Comment: @Sjoerd Ok. Hope you'll get even soon :)

Comment: & Sjoerd, I am sorry I was not clear. I will take a discrete math class this semester which hopefully will help. Sjoerd solution does exactly what I want. Thank You for your attention despite my unclear question. Please Edit the question as you wish  so it is relevant to the forum. Sorry again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `Outer` and `Count`:

```
In[39]:= Flatten[Outer[
  {#1, #2, Count[dalist, {#1, _, #2}]} &,
  DeleteDuplicates@dalist[[All, 1]], 
  DeleteDuplicates@dalist[[All, -1]] ], 1]

Out[39]= {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 2}}
```

Comment: This assumes that all combinations of values present in columns 1 and 3 make up countable pairs. That's not what is stated in the specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation of Sjoerd's second method, that may or may not be easier to read and adapt.

```
Join @@ Table[{i, j, dalist[[All, {1,3}]] ~Count~ {i, j}}, {i,5}, {j,0,1}]
```

One may use `Array` in the same manner:

```
Join @@ Array[{##, dalist[[All, {1,3}]] ~Count~ {##}} &, {5,2}, {1,0}]
```

If your table is large, it will be worthwhile to do the extraction only once:

```
With[{x = dalist[[All, {1,3}]]},
 Join @@ Array[{##, x~Count~{##}} &, {5,2}, {1,0}]
]
```